# Using bash to cycle through files in directory then create sub-directory based on file name

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

What I'm trying to do is use bash to

```
1) cycle through files in a directory 
2) then create a sub-directory based on the file names 
3) then split mp3 files using ffmpeg in 3 second increments.
```

I can get the sub-directories created and the ffmpeg code splits the files up using the correct names.  The issue I seem to be having is the loop.  It creates the split-chirp directory and all it's files but it doesn't process the **pink.mp3** file.  See image below of the starting directory
[image: Start directory]

See image of ending directory
[image: Ending directory]

**It doesn't create the split-pink directory and all the files (I know it's a looping problem just can't figure out why)**

I run the code using the command `bash mp3spl.sh *.mp3`

Code below

```
#!/bin/bash
currentdir=$(pwd) #get current directory

for f in $currentdir/*.mp3
do

fn=`echo "$1" | cut -d'.' -f1` #get just the filename no extension
splitdirname="$currentdir/split-$fn"  #sub directory with correct names 
mkdir -p "$splitdirname" #make split directory
echo "Processing $f"
ffmpeg -i "$1" 2> tmp.txt

    ffmpeg -i "$1" -f segment -segment_time 3 -ar 22050 -ac 1 "$splitdirname/$fn-%03d.mp3"

#rm tmp.txt

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$1` is unnecessary, because you want to loop over all mp3 files.

```
fn=$(basename "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1) #get just the filename no extension
```

I left the rest untouched.

Comment: Thanks that helped/worked I just needed to also change `$1` to `$f` `ffmpeg -i "$f" -f segment -segment_time 3 -ar 22050 -ac 1 "$splitdirname/$fn-%03d.mp3"`

Comment: At the moment this won't work with directories and filenames with spaces in them.  Not sure why.

Comment: Then you have to quote your variables wirh `"$f"` and so on. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with spaces in directories and filenames

```
#!/bin/bash
#run using bash mp3spl.sh
currentdir="$(pwd)" #get current directory


for f in *.mp3   #only look for mp3 files
do

fn=$(basename "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1) #get just the filename no extension

splitdirname="$currentdir/split-$fn" #sub directory with correct names
mkdir -p "$splitdirname" #make split directory
#echo "Processing $f"
ffmpeg -i "$1" 2> tmp.txt

ffmpeg -i "$f" -f segment -segment_time 1200 -ar 22050 -ac 1 "$splitdirname/%03d-$fn.mp3" #split every 20mins

#rm tmp.txt

done
```